# What is wrong with this definition in order to create a key for a service account?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I have implemented the following code, but whenever I run the Google function HTTP trigger, I get the "Error: Could not handle the request" error.  I checked the log file to see the error (below), but just above it is the code I'm trying to run to get a key.  I want to retrieve a key, which I can test out using it to connect to a storage bucket - is that even possible???  It's a way of giving someone a key so they can connect to  bucket and upload some data.  I'm trying to replicate a SAS that Azure uses in order to give access to a storage account.

```
service_account_email = 'demo@appspot.gserviceaccount.com'
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        filename=os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'],
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
    service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        'iam', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
    key = service.projects().serviceAccounts().keys().create(
        name='projects/-/serviceAccounts/' + service_account_email, body={}
        ).execute()
```

> newrequest 6dox145ag5e0 Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py",
> line 402, in run_http_function result =
> _function_handler.invoke_user_function(flask.request) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py",
> line 268, in invoke_user_function return
> call_user_function(request_or_event) File
> "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py",
> line 261, in call_user_function return
> self._user_function(request_or_event) File "/user_code/main.py", line
> 33, in hello_world
> filename=os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'], File
> "/env/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 681, in **getitem** raise
> KeyError(key) from None KeyError: 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'

Comment: Can you explain more your use case? I understood that you want to create key on the fly to let users downloading and uploading data to Cloud Storage, correct?

Comment: Hi Guillaume.  Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is this: 

- User triggers a function by simply going to the URL of a Google function.  The function creates a location in a bucket to store data.  The function also creates a key that the user can then retrieve in order to connect to the storage bucket.  I'd like this key to give them access to, for example, googlebucket/companyname/.  I'm hoping this function will only create a key to allow them access to that path.

- Then after they connect, user uploads data, which triggers another function to review the files.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. But you mustn't do this!

Many points:

- You can't grant the permission on only directory on Cloud Storage. (For information, the directory doesn't exist! It's simply an aggregation of files having the same prefix and displayed like this in the UI. There is [no "object"](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) directory in Cloud Storage).
- You are limited to [10 keys per service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys).
- The service account that you use in `@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` is the App Engine default service account and have, by default, the editor role. A lot of permission and can do almost anything on the project. If you give this to someone on internet, it can break your project or even create a lot on VMs with bitcoin miner on them. And you will pay!

---

The correct pattern is:

- The user call a secured Cloud Functions, with credentials (we can discuss this if you don't know what to use and how to do) -> Don't let publicly accessible a function that grant permissions!
- Use [signedUrl](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) to give access to a specific Cloud Storage location and for a limited period of time for reading or writing actions.

---

Update 1:

To achieve what you want, you need 2 functions:

- The first one that provide the signedUrl. Deploy your [function in private mode `--no-allow-unauthenticated`](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing) (or remove allUsers from the Cloudfunctions.invoker role). Then, when you test, you can do this `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https:...`. If you use an external tool, generate a token with the command `gcloud auth print-access-token`, copy it and add it to the header to your requests. It is valid 1H.
- The second [function will be triggered by Cloud Storage event](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage). When a file is uploaded (finalized), the function will be invoked. Catch the event, get the file metadata from the event (bucket name + file path) and store it in a database.

Because, I don't know what you want to do with your file metadata, I can't recommend a database.

- Cloud SQL if you have relational constraint
- Firestore is your query are simple (no join, no complex filtering)
- BigQuery for analytics

(there are the 3 most affordable)

Comment: OK, you've convinced me to try something else.  I'd like to now try this flow, can you suggest what API to use?

Create an API and set up authentication to it.  Use Insomia/Fiddler to call the API URL and send a file path to upload a file through a Python function.  Upload that file to a database as binary.  

If that's possible, what database should I set up and should I use a specific API that Google offers?  If I should create another question, please let me know and I will.

Comment: Will the Cloud Functions be called by another service or by a user? (To define the type of authentication that you need). Then, I don't understand the file storage. The users upload file to Cloud Storage. Why do you want to store the file as binary in a database? for which reason? And how these data will be used?

Comment: Sorry Guillaume, I misunderstood the request I need to look up.  The file doesn't have to be stored in a database as binary, I only need to store the metadata from the file.  This is a POC so the function would only be called by me.  Any authentication method is fine for now.